# How deep can we go in levels of nested tables in oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle12c

i am trying to do the folowing:

1) create or replace type transaction as object (date Date, description 
   varchar(30));

create or replace type T_transaction as table of transaction;

2) create or replace type account as object (id int, description varchar(30),
   t_transaction T_transaction)
   nested table t_transaction store as xxx1;

create or replace type T_account as table of account;

3) create or replace type user as object (id int, descr varchar(30), t_account 
   T_account)
   nested table t_account store as xxx2;

create or replace type T_user as table of user;

4) create or replace table banks (name varchar(20), users T_user)
   nested table users store as xxx3;

first 2 types were created successfully, but "create or replace type account..." is giving -> Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

is there an advice for creating such database using multiple level of nested tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

I did some research on the subject (object nesting limitations) and here are my findings:

According to [Database Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/datatype-limits.html#GUID-963C79C9-9303-49FE-8F2D-C8AAF04D3095),
every column of a nested table is in effect added to the columns of the host table and the maximum total number of columns in a table is 1000.
So this would be the official upper limit (in case every nested table had a single column).

However, when I did actual testing (on 11g and 12c), I weren't able to create a table with a nesting depth more than 50 because of error 
`ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded`.
Thus I conclude that the maximum possible depth of nesting is 50.

**Initial answer:**

I am not aware of limits on objects nesting but I think they should be reasonably permissive.

Your code fails because you made a few mistakes:
1. Using type names as column names (`date`, `t_account`, etc.);
2. Using `nested table` clause in a wrong place;

The code should go like this:

```
create or replace type transaction_type as object (tx_date Date, description varchar2(30));

create or replace type transaction_tab as table of transaction_type;

create or replace type account_type as object (id int, description varchar(30),
  transactions transaction_tab);

create or replace type account_tab as table of account_type;

create or replace type user_type as object (id int, descr varchar(30), accounts account_tab);

create or replace type user_tab as table of user_type;

CREATE table banks (name varchar(20), users user_tab) 
  nested table users store as xxx3 (
    nested table accounts store as xxx2 (
      nested table transactions store as xxx1
      ));
```

**Checking**

```
INSERT INTO banks VALUES (
  'John', user_tab(
           user_type(1
                     ,'regular user'
           , account_tab(
               account_type(1
                            ,'regular account'
                        , transaction_tab(transaction_type(
                            trunc(sysdate)
                            , 'regular transaction'))
                       ))
          )));
```

---

```
SQL> SELECT *FROM banks;

NAME
--------------------
USERS(ID, DESCR, ACCOUNTS(ID, DESCRIPTION, TRANSACTIONS(TX_DATE, DESCRIPTION)))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John
USER_TAB(USER_TYPE(1, 'regular user', ACCOUNT_TAB(ACCOUNT_TYPE(1, 'regular accou
nt', TRANSACTION_TAB(TRANSACTION_TYPE('04-APR-18', 'regular transaction'))))))
```

**Selecting nested table columns**

```
SELECT b.name, u.id, u.descr, a.id, a.description 
FROM banks b, table(b.users) u, table(u.accounts) a
WHERE u.descr = 'regular user' AND a.description = 'regular account'
```

---

```
NAME  ID  DESCR         ID  DESCRIPTION      
----- --- ------------- --- ---------------- 
John  1   regular user  1   regular account
```

Comment: Thanks.. can you please give an example about selecting a user or selecting an account.